# Function calls with the arguments amount based on condition

Tags: javascript, arguments, conditional-operator, function-call

I have a function called 'func':

```
const otherFunc = (arg1, arg2) => {...}
const func = (condition1, condition2) => {
 condition1 || condition2 ? otherFunc(value, true) : otherFunc(false)
}
```

The previous way works, but i'm wondering if is there is a way to avoid using two different calls to otherFunc. I tried this but is not correct syntax:

```
const func = (condition1, condition2) => {
 otherFunc((condition1 || condition2) && ...[value, true])
}
```

Edit:
It is a simple function to chain if and elses:

```
function is(value, done) {
  return {
    else: (v) => is(done ? value : v, done),
    if: (condition) => (done || condition ? is(value, true) : is(null)),
    get: value,
  };
}
const n = 50000;
console.log(
  is('small')
    .if(n < 1000) 
    .else('big')
    .if(n > 10000)
    .else('medium-big')
    .if(n > 5000)
    .else('medium-small').get,
);
```

Comment: What happens to `arg2` if `arg1` is `false`? If it's not used, perhaps `otherFunc((condition1 || condition2) && value, true)`?

Comment: No, i can't pass true if the condition is not met :(

Comment: Can you pass anything?

Comment: Only a falsy value

Comment: Then perhaps `otherFunc((condition1 || condition2) && value, (condition1 || condition2))`

Comment: Yeah, i wrote a couple of possible anwsers but i'm not really satisfied with that one, is way too complicated as stated in the first anwser.

Comment: Well, if you assign `cond = condition1 || condition2` then it becomes simply `otherFunc(cond && value, cond)`

Comment: Can you show your actual code, please? That `otherFunc` has a weird signature that you probably should change, from all we can tell.

Answer (score 3):

If you can put the arguments into an array, you can then alternate between the arrays to spread into the argument list.

```
otherFunc(
  ...((condition1 || condition2) ? [value, true] : [false])
);
```

That said, it isn't very readable. I'd really prefer

```
if (condition1 || condition2) {
  otherFunc(value, true);
} else {
  otherFunc(false);
}
```

Good maintainable code isn't a golfing competition - being as DRY as absolutely possible isn't always the best approach.

Comment: Another option: `const x = condition1 || condition2; otherFunc(...x ? [value] : [], x);`. But I totally agree with your conclusion :-)